# Is there a desktop file manager which uses HTML+CSS for window layout?

Tags: file-management

File managers (or file browsers) usually use nativ/system "list widgets" to display lists of files and directories (like WxWidget's ListCtrl).

Web-based file managers use classic web techniques to mimic how desktop apps look.

Now, is there a desktop based file manager which uses a browser widget to render the lists n stuff usually done with native widgets? Think "wxHtmlWindow instead of wxListCtrl", or "a thin layer around a WebKit core".

(Background is: hackability without reinventing the wheel. Thus, could be this is more a stackoverflow question)

It should be cross-platform. At least Linux would be great.

Comment: [Webix has a widget](https://webix.com/filemanager/) for that, but it will have to be coupled with the file system. Your best bet to develop one would be to use Electron.

Comment: Could be [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/) is built on a similar stack. Like a "cordova app for desktop". I was hoping for a more old-skool desktop app, built with a native windowing library, then using the HTML widget these libs usually offer to have an embedded browser/rendering widget render a HTML-ish layout.. Does that make sense? Thinks like Electron (which I don't know much about, internal-design-wise) I feel use some internal client-server thing making it slow-(er). TagSpaces at least was quite laggy...